# Is insertAdjacentText a standard javascript method?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6, web-standards

for performance reasons I'd like to use the `insertAdjacentText`-method, but I don't know if it is ECMAScript- (JavaScript)-standard.

Comment: There's not a whole lot of need for that method as there is with `insertAdjacentHTML` since you can simply append a text node.

Comment: Isn't that just `elem.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode('text here'),elem.nextSibling);`? Doesn't seem worthy of an entire new method to me...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

`insertAdjacentText`  is now supported by all browsers after Firefox 47.

Ref: https://caniuse.com/#search=insertAdjacentText

**Original**

According to [dottoro.com](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrsluxu.php) it is not supported by Firefox, but only by the other major browsers, shall might be the reason why there is no entry in the MDN-documentation.

I only found an entry on the [Microsoft Developer Network documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536453(v=vs.85).aspx) for this feature.

So regardless whether it's standard or not, one might use insertAdjacentHTML instead, because it is [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) by all major browsers.

Comment: Using `.insertAdjacentHTML` will work only for situations where the text being inserted can not be confused with any kind of HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

No. Nothing related to the DOM is defined by ECMAScript.

`insertAdjacentText` is defined by the [WHATWG DOM Living Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-insertadjacenttext).

It is [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=insert-adjacent) by all current, major browsers.